# Why does this work for bounded method reference?

Tags: foreach, java-8

In the snippet below, **[1]** seems to yield the expected result whereas, **[2]** throws a ClassCastException as shown in the results below.

Why is a **ClassCastException** thrown when calling iterator() and not when using method reference?

```
 List<String> philosophers = Arrays.asList("Seneca", "Epictetus");
 // [1]
 for (String s : (Iterable<? extends String>) philosophers::iterator) {
     System.out.println(s);
 }

 // [2]
 for (String s: (Iterable<? extends String>) philosophers.iterator()) {
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

[1] (Result when using method reference)

```
`Seneca`
`Epictetus`
```

[2] (Result when calling iterator())

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayItr cannot be cast to class java.lang.Iterable`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different things.

`philosophers::iterator` is a **function** which when invoked, takes 0 arguments and returns an Iterator. As it happens, this is compatible with the definition of Iterable, since that interface has a single abstract method which does just that.

`philosophers.iterator()` does not return a function; it returns an Iterator. An Iterator is not an Iterable so the cast fails.

---

It is worth nothing that there's no good reason to do either of these. The first is basically only working by accident. That's a very unintuitive way to use a method reference. Just do

```
for (String s : philosophers)
```

Comment: Since Iterable has a single abstract method, why isn't it annotated with FunctionalInterface ?

Comment: @George Because `FunctionalInterface` is designed to specify *intent*. The intent of Iterable was not to be one, it just happens to qualify. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166187/why-isnt-functionalinterface-used-on-all-the-interfaces-in-the-jdk-that-qualif